# SimpleDateFormat timezone bug on Android

Tags: java, android

I've been trying to isolate a bug in my application. I succeeded in producing the following "riddle":

```java
SimpleDateFormat f1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
SimpleDateFormat f2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
Date d = f1.parse("2012-01-01T00:00:00+0700");
String s1 = f1.format(d); // 2011-12-31T18:00:00+0700
String s2 = f2.format(d); // 2011-12-31T18:00:00+0100
```

I get the values in comments when I run this code **on Android API 7** (yes, really). This behavior depends on particular Java implementation.

My questions are:

- Why s1 does not equal s2?
- And more importantly, **why s1 is incorrect?** While `s2` points to a proper point in time, `s1` does not. There seems to be a bug in Android's SimpleDateFormat implementation.

**ANSWER TO QUESTION 1:** See the answer by BalusC:

- *[After using `SimpleDateFormat#parse`] any TimeZone value that has previously been set by a call to setTimeZone may need to be restored for further operations.*

**ANSWER TO QUESTION 2:** See the answer by wrygiel (myself).

- *This is due to a bug in Android 2.1 (API 7).*

Comment: I ran your code. Both outputs are the same when I run

Comment: I run in on Android API 7. Maybe this matters. I will update the description.

Comment: I run your code as well. s1 and s2 is the same - the problem lies somewhere in your "not visible" (for us) code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is mentioned in javadoc of [`DateFormat#parse()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse%28java.lang.String,%20java.text.ParsePosition%29):

> Parse a date/time string according to the given parse position. For example, a time text `"07/10/96 4:5 PM, PDT"` will be parsed into a Date that is equivalent to `Date(837039900000L)`.
>
> By default, parsing is lenient: If the input is not in the form used by this object's format method but can still be parsed as a date, then the parse succeeds. Clients may insist on strict adherence to the format by calling [`setLenient(false)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setLenient%28boolean%29).
>
> This parsing operation uses the [`calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#calendar) to produce a `Date`. As a result, the `calendar's` date-time fields and the `TimeZone` value may have been overwritten, depending on subclass implementations. Any `TimeZone` value that has previously been set by a call to [`setTimeZone`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setTimeZone%28java.util.TimeZone%29) may need to be restored for further operations.

Note the last paragraph. It unfortunately doesn't explain *when* exactly this will occur. To fix your particular problem you need to explicitly set the desired timezone before the formatting operation.

As to the mutability of `SimpleDateFormat` itself, this is known for years. You should never create and assign an instance of it as a static or class variable, but always as a method (threadlocal) variable.

Comment: God, this is beyond me... I get mutability and thread issues, but all this happens in a single thread. `Date` objects have proper timezones set. Why the formatter does not access them for itself? It doesn't matter if it outputs a value in a different timezone **as long as it is correct**, and `s1` **is not**. I can't see WHY this ISN'T a bug.

Comment: Why do you have 2 instances in the same thread? All with all, I agree you, `DateFormat` (and `Date`) are not the best of Java SE. That's why JodaTime is extolled.

Comment: I had only one instance, but it produced an invalid value (s1). I added the second one to get a valid one (s2).

Comment: If I parsed s1 again, I would get a d2 which does not equal d. I can't see how the documentation you cited explains that.

Comment: @wrygiel - f1 is used twice, while f2 is used once.  when you use f1 to _parse_ the initial date string, it _changes_ the TimeZone of f1.  thus, f1 and f2 now have different TimeZones, hence the different output when you format d.

Comment: @jtahlborn - you are right, but this doesn't answer my second question. The key issue was - why s1 is incorrect (it doesn't matter if s1 and s2 are in different timezones, but they are actually pointing to different times!). I already found the most probable answer - there is a bug in Android's implementation of SimpleDateFormat (see the links in my own answer).

Answer (score 7):

This is due to [a bug](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8258) in Android 2.1 (API 7). It seems that Android programmers missed [some undocumented Java behavior](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4827490) (which is classified as an unfixable bug itself!) in their implementation of Android 2.1.

Comment: You should have quoted Java's linked bug (it's gone now); see another permanent Java bug: stackoverflow.com/ **[JTextField render bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48203021/8740349)**

Answer (score 0):

Your question intrigued me so I went ahead and compiled your code. The result? As expected...

```
2011-12-31T18:00:00+0100
2011-12-31T18:00:00+0100
```

The two values are the same, are you using some concurrency? Maybe the variable gets changed on another thread right before the `f2.format(d)`.

Comment: Well, I am not. Currently I have these statements in my Application#onCreate method.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to compare s1 and s2 by running the same program. they come equal to me. 
[image]

Comment: I guess it depends on implementation. On Android API 7 you would get the same values as I did. I promise ;)