# JTextField render bug if Text-Not-Fitting (JDK 7 till 18)

Tags: java, swing, rendering, custom-controls, jtextfield

### JTextField has wrong text render on RIGHT_TO_LEFT component orientation

We need a **workaround**, since whenever `JTextField` is filled with text that contains:

- `Right to left text` like Arabic,
- `Latin numbers`,
- and `Latin text`.

Then `JTextField` renders text parts at unexpected locations.

> (It only renders right if the complete text Fits inside the `JTextField`.)

The text we use to reproduce is:

- `صندوق ۴۰×۳۰ پایه دار وایرنگ میتر تک فاز`

**Other info**:

- Above text is just name of a product, added inside an accounting software we created, but our users have match more render failures than we could reproduce.
- We reported at: [JDK-8194733](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8194733)
- We have no experience with a custom-render in Java to make workaround, but render of entire text not considering the limit, and clipping that, should do the trick.

---

## Source code for an executable test case:

```java
//
// Like you may notice, below code shows simple JTextField, 
// but once you resize the Window smaller than the text Fits,
// then you experience numbers dancing (moving around randomly).
//
// And trying to select parts of text is even more fatal (random parts are rendered).
//
package test;

import java.awt.ComponentOrientation;

public class JavaBug extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JavaBug frame = new JavaBug();
        frame.show();
    }
    
    public JavaBug() {
        javax.swing.JTextField textField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        
        textField.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 24)); // NOI18N
        
        // Below is just name of a product, added inside an accounting software.
        textField.setText("\u0635\u0646\u062F\u0648\u0642 \u06F4\u06F0×\u06F3\u06F0 \u067E\u0627\u06CC\u0647 \u062F\u0627\u0631 \u0648\u0627\u06CC\u0631\u0646\u06AF \u0645\u06CC\u062A\u0631 \u062A\u06A9 \u0641\u0627\u0632");
        textField.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
        
        getContentPane().add(textField);
        pack();
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null); //enusre get showed at screen center
        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

#### Screen shots

Just running above code results to:
[image: just run]

After resize, to something less:
[image: after resize]

---

Development Kit or Runtime version:

- java version "1.8.0_25"
- Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b18)
- Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)

Comment: What if you use JTextArea or JEditorPane rather than JTextField?

Comment: Whta is the problem you actually have? Half of the text is visible? Size is not calculated correctly? Do you need read only content or it should be editable? For JEditorPane/JtextPane yu can take a look on custom GlyphPainter - http://java-sl.com/gp_effects.html

Comment: thanks for fast comments. tried JTextArea just now but did not managed to resize it until the text size is more then the widgets size and text does not fit but we do need widget that we can resize until text does not fit for our accounting program where we use it as table cell editor

Comment: also we think JTextArea does not support navigate to hidden text parts without scrollbar

Comment: 1 and 2: the problem is visual once you resize and text does not fit numbers move and when you select text in that state random parts are rendered. 3: may be size is not calculated correctly by render its java.swing related. 4: we do need editable content. 5: will try JEditorPane/JtextPane but custom GlyphPainter is too advanced for us except you link tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.html.HTMLEditorKit;
import java.awt.*;

public class JavaBug extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JavaBug frame = new JavaBug();
        frame.show();
    }

    public JavaBug() {
        JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
        textPane.setEditorKit(new HTMLEditorKit());
        textPane.setText("<html><font size='+2'>\u0635\u0646\u062F\u0648\u0642 \u06F4\u06F0×\u06F3\u06F0 \u067E\u0627\u06CC\u0647 \u062F\u0627\u0631 \u0648\u0627\u06CC\u0631\u0646\u06AF \u0645\u06CC\u062A\u0631 \u062A\u06A9 \u0641\u0627\u0632</font></html>");
        textPane.getDocument().putProperty("i18n", Boolean.TRUE);
        JPanel noWrapPanel = new JPanel( new BorderLayout() );
        noWrapPanel.add( textPane );
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( noWrapPanel );
        scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);

        /* without below right to left force there is an other bug when we press home and
         * try to navigate to end using left key it will never get at end and fall back at start. kind of crazy bug */
        java.util.Locale arabic = new java.util.Locale("ar", "KW");
        ComponentOrientation arabicOrientation = ComponentOrientation.getOrientation(arabic);
        textPane.applyComponentOrientation(arabicOrientation);

        getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
        pack();
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null); //enusre get showed at screen center
        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

Comment: this is working except your program is left to right and we do not know how to force only right to left if needed

Comment: You can try to add `<span dir="ltr">text</span>` to force left to right. Also on resize you can try to call setCaretPosition() to scroll or even update viewport's rectangle to point to the end of text.

Comment: I used to work with deep font rendering things including LTR/RTL texts and it's not simple:). Would require significant efforts (but doable)

Comment: Have not match experience with html tags but 'span' did not work. anyway big problem here again is user can edit and use Ctrl+A to clear all content and even remove font size! can we change font size in an other way?

Comment: User will not be able to remove the font size at all. It's part of formatting. Tags are not editable by user.